Quadratic fermionic Hamiltonian of two modes
I was reading the thesis "A Quantum Information Perspective of Fermionic Quantum Many-Body Systems" by Christina V. Kraus (https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/811670/811670.pdf) where it is shown that any quadratic fermionic Hamiltonian H of two modes k, −k is up to a common factor and basis change of the form $$H=\alpha \mathbb{1}+\sin \theta\left(n_k+n_{-k}\right)+\cos \theta\left(P_k^{\dagger}+P_k\right)$$
with $n_{-k}=a_{-k}^{\dagger}a_{-k}$, $n_k=a_k^{\dagger}a_k$, $P_k^{\dagger}=a_k^{\dagger}a_{-k}^{\dagger}$ and $P_{k}=a_{-k}a_{k}$
Now given the form of quadratic fermionic Hamiltonian is $$H=\frac{i}{4} c^T G c=\frac{i}{4} \sum_{k>l} G_{k l}\left[c_k, c_l\right]$$ with $c_{2 j-1}=a_j^{\dagger}+a_j, c_{2 j}=(-i)\left(a_j^{\dagger}-a_j\right)$, which satisfy $\left\{c_k, c_l\right\}=2 \delta_{k l}$.
Can anyone show how to obtain the former form of the hamiltonian from the latter?
My solution: I considered $c_{1}=a_k^{\dagger}+a_k, c_{2}=(-i)\left(a_k^{\dagger}-a_k\right)$ and $c_{3}=a_{-k}^{\dagger}+a_{-k}, c_{4}=(-i)\left(a_{-k}^{\dagger}-a_{-k}\right)$. Even though I am getting the terms $\mathbb{1}$, $n_{-k}=a_{-k}^{\dagger}a_{-k}$, $n_k=a_k^{\dagger}a_k$, $P_k^{\dagger}=a_k^{\dagger}a_{-k}^{\dagger}$ and $P_{k}=a_{-k}a_{k}$ in the expression of $H$, i am getting some additional cross term like $a_k^{\dagger}a_{-k}$ and $a_{-k}^{\dagger}a_k$. Clearly these terms are not present in the former expression of H. So what am I doing wrong?

What form is $P_k$ supposed to have?

The OP should define each term properly when they first show up.  Yes, it really is too much to ask people to keep reading until the end to see $P_k = a^{\dagger} a^{\dagger}$.  Also, a link to the referenced article would be helpful.  But anyway, $a^{\dagger}{k} a{-k}$ doesn't conserve momentum and is forbidden by translational symmetry.

link for the corresponding paper https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.79.012306 (section IV.C)

Can you please tell how does the $sin\theta$ and $cos\theta$ appear?

@Vokaylop Can you explain why any quadratic hamiltonian should have translation symmetry?

Given any two real numbers $A$ and $B$, you can always parameterize them as $A = R \cos \theta$ and $B = R \sin \theta$.  And then you can rescale the Hamiltonian to bring $R \rightarrow 1$.  As for translational invariance, I am only guessing (though it is an educated guess.)  You should read the article carefully to find out the assumptions made by the author.

@Vokaylop It is unclear whether the P_k at the end is what it is claimed to be in the thesis, or just a particular ansatz made by the OP for some such object.

@Sakh10 Are we talking about the thesis or the paper?

@NorbertSchuch I agree in principle; just giving benefit of the doubt to the OP.  And even then I am serious with the "this is too much" comment.  That is terrible writing by the OP.

@NorbertSchuch It is available both in thesis as well as in the paper

@Sakh10 Please consider adding links to the post.

@NorbertSchuch I have added the link

They are just switching from Dirac fermions to Majorana ones. The boson analogue of this is to switch from annihilation/creation operators to canonical conjugate position and momentum. You just substitute (I will use $c$ for the Dirac fermions and $\gamma$ for Majorana, more standard):
$$
c_k = \frac{\gamma_k^1-i\gamma_k^2}2
$$
with the canonical anti commutation relations:
$$
\{c_k,c_l^\dagger\} = \delta_{kl} \quad \{\gamma_i^j,\gamma_k^l\} = 2\delta_{ij}\delta^{kl}
$$
substituting gives:
$$
n_k = \frac i2\gamma_k^2\gamma_k^1 \\
P_k = \frac14(\gamma_{-k}^1\gamma_k^1-\gamma_{-k}^2\gamma_k^2)-\frac i4(\gamma_{-k}^1\gamma_k^2+\gamma_{-k}^2\gamma_k^1)
$$
so:
$$
H = \alpha+\frac i2[\sin\theta(\gamma_k^2\gamma_k^1+\gamma_{-k}^2\gamma_{-k}^1)-\cos\theta(\gamma_{-k}^1\gamma_k^2+\gamma_{-k}^2\gamma_k^1)]
$$
You can now easily identify $G$.
